# iOS UIDatePicker/UIPickerView returning wrong value when used with interval? iOS SDK bug?

Tags: ios, date, uipickerview, intervals, uidatepicker

I have a UIPickerView under iOS running in time mode with interval set to 15 mins:

[image]

When asking the view for the time that is actually shown, it does not return the time corresponding to the chosen interval setting but rather the actual time:

[image]

The view returns 2017-09-18 13:14:00 +0000 which is wrong, as the shown time is 1:00 PM or 13:00 respectively:

```
        ft = String(describing: tf.string(from: timeSelectorPickerView.date))
```

I think this is a bug in UIDatePickerView, because the attribute 'date' is described as follows:

[image]

Is there any known issue on this - or at least an elegant workaround?

Comment: Try Using  NSDateFormatter()

And formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00") may be it's help you.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. This is my solution:

```
pickerDate -= pickerDate.timeIntervalSince1970.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy:  Double(self.timeSelectorPickerView.minuteInterval * 60))
```

Asking the PickerView of its `minuteInterval` setting and subtracting modulo the minuteInterval setting seconds from its value, resulting in the correct time that is shown by the PickerView with `minuteInterval` activated.

Hope this information helps others stumbling into this.

This is still a bug Apple should fix.